# character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Tags: jquery-mobile, utf-8

Im not sure why but im getting these errors:

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

I'm new to this and am not sure what this means . I assume something is going wrong within the header. Did some research but no real clues as to what is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>FONWV</title>
<script src = "jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type = "text/javascript</script>
<script src = "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type = "text/javascript"</script>
<link href = "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page"> 
<div data-role="header"><a href = "#" data-rel="back" data-add-back-
btn="true" data-icon="arrow-1" data-iconpos="notext"></a></div> 
<div data-role="content">
    <p id = "heading">Is Nursing For You?</p>
    <br/>
    <div id = "div1" align="center"></div>
</div> 
<div data-role="footer table" id = "foot" data-position="fixed">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><h1 id = "alignLeft">Future</th></h1>
        <th><h1 id = "socialMediaText alignCenter">Get Social With Us!</h1>
</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id = "alignLeft">Telephone: 343-464-3120</td>
    <tr>
        <td = "alignLeft">Email: future.com</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your original example first off don't have spaces surrounding '=' in html tags. Also you didn't close one of your quotations in the first script tag, nor the tag itself and I don't see a closing body or html tag at the end of the example.

change the first tag to:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then after that make sure you close everything.

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>FONWV</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-add-back- btn="true" data-icon="arrow-1" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p id="heading">Is Nursing For You?</p>
      <br/>
      <div id="div1" align="center"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer table" id="foot" data-position="fixed">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h1 id="alignLeft">Future</th>
          </h1>
          <th>
            <h1 id="socialMediaText alignCenter">Get Social With Us!</h1>
          </th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="alignLeft">Telephone: 343-464-3120</td>
          <tr>
            <td="alignLeft">Email: future.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </th>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```